# Excluding a specific project code from build

Tags: angular

I have created an angular application with multiple projects.

I want to remove a specific project and its code completely from the build.

Please note all the projects are connected through routing. So doing Ng serve will make all the projects available.
The same goes for the build. I should be able to run npm build and it should only build specific project build.
To achieve above, if I remove the project from angular.json file, will that work and how I can verify that.
Please help.

Comment: Usually you only build a single angular project at a time when using [`ng build`](https://angular.io/cli/build). Or are you not talking about a project as the angular build documentation defines it but something else?

Comment: @Igor yes angular build that way. Even for multiple projects also it will do the same as main app is connected via routes for other projects. Question is how I can avoid specific project to be included and its code in the final build. Important thing is I want to do it with this command only ng build, not with ng build --project=myproj

Comment: Perhaps create a new configuration that you only use with a prod build and specify this in that configuration. Then pass the configuration name to the ng build cli command.

Comment: What about if I remove a specific project from angular.json file, just for making a build. Will it do this job? And how I can cross check that?

Comment: I am not sure, try and find out.

Comment: Tried, couldn't figure out. Anyway thanks for your help.